# asp.net returning the contents of a partial view

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

I'm trying to dynamically add a row to my table in a Create scaffold...

I used JavaScript to have a button append HTML code the topmost div.

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <button class="control-label col-md-2" id="btnAddField">Add Question with One Answer</button>

            <div class="col-md-10">

                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {

                    <div id="fields"></div>

                }


                <div style="color:blue"><b>Data:</b> @ViewBag.Data</div>
                <!-- JS includes -->
                <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var $fields = $('#fieldsTop');
                    $('#btnAddField').click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        $('@Html.Partial("_SingleQuestion")').appendTo($fields);
                    });
                });

                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is obviously duplicated when clicking on the btnAddField.

If _SingleQuestion opens up with a  the page gets submitted. Otherwise, example, if i type test the div is appended. Why is the page being posted and how can I prevent it?

why is it when i try to dynamically add a div with the class form-group my page gets posted?

Comment: Sorry! What is happening now ? What is your expected behavior ?

Comment: When I try ot add a div with the class form-group my entire page get's "posted" and it refreshes... I just want to dynamically add that blob of code to the #fieldsTop div!

Comment: With the code you shared, it should not post the form.

Comment: Open your browser console and see what is happening when the page loads. Are you seeing any script errors ?